# I am creating ul li submenu for responsive,I dont know how to write for mobile device so far I have done this

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am creating ul li submenu for responsive,I dont know how to write for mobile device so far I have done this,Can any one help me to finish this menu. I have written for mobile alone if I execute in firefox  and gave the ctrl+shift+m,It is not coming properly.kindly share you knowledge.below I have listed my sample code:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>BRIGHT BRIAN</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="css/images/faveicon1.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div id="logo">
                            <a href="#"><span class="red">BRIGHT&nbsp;</span><span class="blue">BRAIN</span></a>
                        </div>
                            <!-- navigation -->
                            <nav id="navigation">
                                <ul>
                                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">About us</a>
                                    <ul class="submenu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Vission</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Special Features</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </li>
                                  <li> <a href="#">Course</a></li>
                                  <li> <a href="#">Feedback</a>
                                    <ul class="submenu">
                                        <li><a href="#">From Training</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">From Student</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">From Parents</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </li>
                                  <li> <a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                                  <li> <a href="#">Franchise</a>
                                    <ul class="submenu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Low investment</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Student work</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Monthly good income</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </li>
                                  <li> <a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                              </nav>
                            <!-- navigation -->
                    </div><!--End of container-->
                </div><!--End of header-->
            </header><!--End of header element-->
        </div><!--End of wrapper-->
    </body>
</html>
```

For default css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    color: #808080;
    background: #efefef url(images/body.png) repeat-x 0 0;
}
.header {
    background: url(images/header1%20copy.png) repeat-x 0 0;
    height: 58px;
    padding: 29px 0 0 0;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Comic_Sans_MS;
    src: url(../font/Comic_Sans_MS.ttf);
}
#logo a {
    font-family: Comic_Sans_MS;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 0px;
}
#logo {
    width:250px;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    float:left;
}
.red {
    font-family: Comic_Sans_MS;
    color: #E31C00;
}
.blue {
    font-family: Comic_Sans_MS;
    color: #29166F;
}
.header .container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
#navigation {
    float:left;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width:750px;
}
#navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#navigation ul li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 44px;
}
#navigation ul li a {
    color: #77777b;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navigation ul li a:hover, #navigation ul li.active a {
    color: #2497e0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navigation ul li:hover .submenu {
    display: block;
}
#navigation ul .submenu {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 800px;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
#navigation ul .submenu li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

For mobile css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document (common width:260px;)*/

@media only screen and (max-width:530px)
{
    .header .container {
    width: 260px !important;
    }
    #logo {
        float:left;
        width:260px !important;
        text-align:center;
    }
    #logo a {
        font-size:25px !important;
    }
    #navigation {
        float:left !important;
        width:260px !important;
    }
    #navigation ul li{
        float:left !important;
        width:260px !important;
        background-color:#CCCCCC;
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit of advice, get rid of all the !important. It will cause you so much trouble when you come to make changes at a later date. If all those !important's are needed then you're doing something drastically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
.header .container {
    width: 480px !important;
    }
```

you have to set the container size properly 260 is small

Comment: thanks but i am looking for small device then i will work for 480px for wide mobile,my question how do i bring into responsive mode for  mobile what property i have to use  in css for mobile. guide me

Comment: i am not sure what you want to know but if you are looking for how mobile css will activate then @media only screen and (max-width:530px) itself tell browser to change following css when media device screen size is max 530

Comment: try to adjust screen size you will see the effect

Comment: thank you, you got me point If i adjust screen size the menu ul li is not coming in proper way for that only i am asking,once i complete these thing i will move to tablet size, could you please guide me for menu part alone

Comment: and i am also asking what is the proper way you want. can you define that in words like no space in front of header or something like that

Comment: ok i make you very simple if you execute in firefox and give  ctrl+shift+m you can adjust screen size,in that the menu what I made is not adjust according to the resolution.for 260px or 480 for both pixel it is not coming, I hope you understand my words. thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width:530px)
{
    .header .container {
    width: 260px !important;
  margin:0px;
    }
```